# Connect RPi to Hard Drive Connected to Router

Tags: networking, hard-drive

I am trying to connect my Pi to a hard drive connected to my router. [image]

This was easy to do on Windows, but I can't figure out how to do it on here. Please help

Comment: The router is a TP-Link ac1750, by the way, but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: This is a generic Linux problem that's no different on the Pi. You need to find a tutorial on using any Linux as a Samba client.